# Order of "anova" Arguments and Understanding Stepwise Variable Addition Effect

Tags: r, logistic, anova, generalized-linear-model, chi-squared-test

I was trying to fit a model with the following code:

```
m1 <- glm(data = Mroz, lfp~ k5+ k618 + age + wc + hc+ lwg+ inc,
family = binomial)
```

And then to understand whether dropping two independent variables (k5,k618) would improve the model or not:

```
m2 <- update(m1, .~. -k5-k618)
```

To understand the effect I used the following with corresponding output:

```
anova(m1,m2,test = "Chisq")
```

Output:

```
Model 1: lfp ~ k5 + k618 + age + wc + hc + lwg + inc
Model 2: lfp ~ age + wc + hc + lwg + inc
  Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance  Pr(>Chi)    
1       745     905.27                          
2       747     971.75 -2  -66.485 3.655e-15 ***
```

If I change the order of input like this with corresponding output:

```
anova(m2,m1,test = "Chisq")
```

Output:

```
Model 1: lfp ~ age + wc + hc + lwg + inc
Model 2: lfp ~ k5 + k618 + age + wc + hc + lwg + inc
  Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance  Pr(>Chi)    
1       747     971.75                          
2       745     905.27  2   66.485 3.655e-15 ***
```

With both the p-values being equal means: 'These two models differ significantly." But, how do I know which one is the better fit? Does the value of deviance indicate that? I am not sure. Regardless of I go forward/backward while including variables, how do I know if 1>>2 or 2>>1?

IE: Is accuracy a monotonic function of the number of inputs added sequentially?

Answer (score 0):

The null hypothesis is that constraints (i.e., constraining the coefficients to zero) are present in the population. Rejecting the null hypothesis means that there evidence that it's not the case that both variables have coefficients of zero in the population. Said more succinctly, a small p-value lends support for the larger model (i.e., the unconstrained one, with more parameters being estimated). The order of the models in the `anova()` function doesn't affect the interpretation of the test results.

Comment: That means adding more and more variable is a monotonous process? That it will always lead to a better fit? It seems true, but cant get it completely.

Comment: The likelihood in the sample will always increase with added parameters being estimated. The likelihood increasing in the sample doesn't mean that the model with more parameters corresponds to the population model. In ordinary least squares, this is analogous to how the sample $R^2$ always increases as more variables are included, even if the population coefficient is zero.